# Execute Process Task in SSIS for Python Script

Tags: python, batch-file, ssis, package

I'm trying to execute a python script by SSIS Execute Process Task. The Python script is correct. This script read data from yfinance and  do some calculation, then export the calculation data into database. I need to execute this script every day. I make a batch file for execution of script file:

[image]

I used SSIS Execute SQL Task and configure properties follow:

[image]

But I received this error:

[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "D:....\batch_ssis.bat" "" at "", The process exit code was "9009" while the expected was "0".

Answer (score 0):

That exit code 9009 comes from windows, it tries to execute batch_ssis.bat and can't resolve the information contained in the batch file

Make sure you do not have spaces in your path D:.....\ , if you do add quotations to your path so it looks like this "D:......"

Also ensure that python is installed and configured in your [PATH windows environment variable](https://medium.com/@omoshalewa/why-you-should-add-python-to-path-and-how-58693c17c443) so that you can call python from any directory within windows

Answer (score 0):

Set **FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue** to False.

This worked for me today. It ignores whatever exit code the batch script returns.

In my case the expected job runs well but SSIS package failed because of the 9009 exit code returned. I still haven't figured out why.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correctly pointing to your file.

*The file was not found.*

**Error Code 9009 means error file not found. The error can be happening in the Bat or somewhere on your machine(like Windows or Mac), but the error itself simply means a bad path.**

Try to point directly to your Python file, and see if any difference seems the Path you mask is not correct.

[image: 9009 error]

See also if this video can help:

[Fix 9009 Error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdLyFDwJt2Q)